# WordPress: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 after Duplicate page with Duplicator

Tags: php, wordpress

after cloning a page on localhost via Duplicator I have the problem that when I want to submit forms not logged in I get this.

```
VM146:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I have disabled plugins, used wordpress database repair and updated the clone to the latest WordPress version to rule out corrupt files.

JS and CSS files (grunt) I have also recreated.

The PHP functions are registered as follows.

```
// Add the Action for sell_form
add_action('admin_post_create_pre_lead', 'create_pre_lead');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_create_pre_lead', 'create_pre_lead');
```

The only difference I don't understand is the status code for the Ajax URL
(http://localhost/mysite/wp-admin/admin-post.php)

```
Status Code: 200 OK (Logged in)
Status Code: 302 Found (Not logged in)
```

I think this is already the problem. I just don't know where to find it and how to fix it. Because the code is 1 to 1 the same.

**Edit**
Found the Problem. Posted the Solution as an answer below.

Comment: Sounds like the ajax is receiving HTML code instead of JSON. Bring up your browser's developer console and check the Network tab for the response.

Comment: _"The PHP functions are registered as follows."_ - what PHP functions? What are they supposed to _do_?

Comment: @aynber When i open the console under firefox, the tab for the rspone is empty. i only see under request, the post variables i pass, but they all look correct.

Comment: @CBroe The function creates a new post at the end under a Custom Post Type. With some information from the form. It also scans already created posts to see if there is a match with the post that should be created to see if it is the same user.

Everything that already worked, only the duplicate with duplicator now makes these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem....
Where in the following code "wrongFolderName" is written, was the problem.  Of course the cloned page was accessible locally under another url. greetings go to my predecessor :-)

```
add_action( "admin_init", "redirect_non_admin_users" );
function redirect_non_admin_users() {
    
    if(isLocalhost()) {
        
        $localhosturl = "/wrongFolderName/wp-admin/admin-post.php";
        
        if ( !current_user_can( "manage_options" ) && ($localhosturl != $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ) {     
            wp_redirect(home_url());
            exit;
        };
    }else{
        if ( !current_user_can( "manage_options" ) && ("/wp-admin/admin-post.php" != $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ) {
            wp_redirect(home_url());
            exit;
        };  
    }

}
```